# Checking if java.lang.Class object is class (not enum, not annotation, not interface and so on) in Java 8 and Java 17?

Tags: java, class, java-8, bytecode, java-17

Checking if `java.lang.Class` object is `class` (not `enum`, not `annotation`, not `interface` and so on)  in Java 8 and Java 17?

I found a similarly question ([Determine if java.lang.Class object represents a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408447/determine-if-java-lang-class-object-represents-a-class)), but it isn't very satisfying and it is incompatible in Java 17.

Comment: Why is it incompatible with Java 17? As far as I'm aware, the solution presented in the linked question still works in Java 17 (though you probably also want to check `isRecord()` in Java 17 if you don't consider those classes either).

Comment: `record` is a new type in Java 17.   And `...which isn't very satisfying, as you have to revisit that definition when new features are added to Java (like enums, annotations, ...).`

Comment: It might not be "very satisfying", but it is the only way. As such, your question is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Why is an `enum` or a `record` not a class?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). As [Brian Goetz said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408447/determine-if-java-lang-class-object-represents-a-class#comment128381257_43408447), “first you have to decide what you mean by ‘class’, and why you are even making such find distinctions”.